# Replacing TTY with a script in CentOS 6

Tags: centos, startup, upstart

How would I go about replacing a TTY with a custom script in CentOS 6.  CentOS 6 uses upstart instead of the standard SysV init scripts, so I'm having difficulty figuring out how it all works.

Typically (in SysV init scripts), I would edit /etc/inittab and replace one of the mingetty lines with my script, like this:

```
1:2345:respawn:/root/myscript tty1
```

However, with Upstart, this file doesn't the relevant lines, so I'm unsure of how to accomplish this.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation?  The [RedHat documentation](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Migration_Planning_Guide/ch04s02.html) has a section on service initialization, and there is of course a website for Upstart as well.

Comment: I did, the documentation wasn't very helpful about replacing an existing tty with something else.

Comment: It looks like you've figured it out anyway.  Congrats!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've figured it out.

First I modified /etc/init/start-ttys.conf to have this for the script section:

```
script
    . /etc/sysconfig/init
    for tty in $(echo $ACTIVE_CONSOLES) ; do
          [ "$RUNLEVEL" = "5" -a "$tty" = "$X_TTY" ] && continue
            if [ "$tty" == "/dev/tty1" ]; then
                    initctl start myjob TTY=$tty
                    continue
            fi
            initctl start tty TTY=$tty
    done
end script
```

I then created /etc/init/myjob.conf:

```
stop on runlevel [012456]

respawn
exec /usr/bin/openvt -c 1 -f -e /root/myscript
```

This ultimately starts /root/myscript on tty1, instead of mingetty.  I'm unsure if this the is simplest way of doing it, but it works quite nicely.